# Shell script While loop

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am messing with shell scripting and stuck in some comparison in while loop

```
while [$size -le $MAX] 
do
------
done
```

The above loop is not working. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have spaces around `[` and `]`.

Say:

```
while [ $size -le $MAX ]
```

`[` is a command, also known as `test`.  When you say `[$size`, the shell interprets it as a string and not as a command.

Comment: Thaank u devnull and @dogbane for replying . That solved my headache. 
That little space raged me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need spaces around the brackets, like this: `while [ $size -le $MAX ]`.

However, it's more readable if you use bash's arithmetic expression instead:

```
while (( size <= MAX )) 
do

done
```